# Mocking generic WCF ClientChannelWrapper async calls

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, moq, channelfactory

I recently developed a Silverlight application which uses [Mark J Millers `ClientChannelWrapper<T>`](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2010/03/08/mvvm-with-prism-101-ndash-part-6b-wrapping-iclientchannel.aspx) to communicate with the WCF service layer (effectively killing the service reference and wrapping `IClientChannel` and `ClientChannelFactory`).
Here is the interface:

```
public interface IClientChannelWrapper<T> where T : class
{
    IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Func<T, IAsyncResult> function);
    void Dispose();
    void EndInvoke(Action<T> action);
    TResult EndInvoke<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> function);
}
```

The Wrapper basically takes a generic async service interface (which might have been generated by slsvcutil or hand crafted after the WCF `ServiceContract`) and wraps the calls to ensure that in case of a channel fault, a new channel gets created.
Typical usage looks like this:

```
 public WelcomeViewModel(IClientChannelWrapper<IMyWCFAsyncService> service)
    {
        this.service = service;
        this.synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext();
        this.isBusy = true;
        this.service.BeginInvoke(m => m.BeginGetCurrentUser(new AsyncCallback(EndGetCurrentUser), null));
    }

private void EndGetCurrentUser(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        string strResult = "";
        service.EndInvoke(m => strResult = m.EndGetCurrentUser(result));
        this.synchronizationContext.Send(
                    s =>
                    {
                        this.CurrentUserName = strResult;
                        this.isBusy = false;
                    }, null);
    }
```

It all works fine but now I'd like to unit test the view models which use the `ClientChannelWrapper`.
I've set up a simple unit test using Moq:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void WhenCreated_ThenRequestUserName()
    {
        var serviceMock = new Mock<IClientChannelWrapper<IMyWCFAsyncService>>();
        var requested = false;

        //the following throws an exception
        serviceMock.Setup(svc => svc.BeginInvoke(p => p.BeginGetCurrentUser(It.IsAny<AsyncCallback>(), null))).Callback(() => requested = true);


        var viewModel = new ViewModels.WelcomeViewModel(serviceMock.Object);
        Assert.IsTrue(requested);
    }
```

I get a NotSupportedException:

> Unsupported expression: p => p.BeginGetCurrentUser(IsAny(), null).

I'm pretty new to Moq but I guess there is some problem with the `ClientChannelWrapper` using generic Service interfaces. Trying to wrap my head around this for quite some time now, maybe someone has an idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I finally got it.
Here are the details:

As so often, the solution was right in front of me since it was in Mark J Millers concrete implementation of the IClientChannelWrapper. In there he provides two constructors, one taking in a string of the WCF endpoint name (which I use in production code) and a second one:

```
public ClientChannelWrapper(T service)
    {
        m_Service = service;
    }
```

Without further ado, here's my new test code:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void WhenCreated_ThenRequestUserName()
    {
        var IMySvcMock = new Mock<IMyWCFAsyncService>();
        var serviceMock = new ClientChannelWrapper<IMyWCFAsyncService>(IMySvcMock.Object);
        var requested = false;

        IMySvcMock.Setup(svc => svc.BeginGetCurrentUser(It.IsAny<AsyncCallback>(), null)).Callback(() => requested = true);
        var viewModel = new ViewModels.WelcomeViewModel(serviceMock);

        Assert.IsTrue(requested);
    }
```

So I basically ignore the interface of the ChannelWrapper and create a new instance of it with the Mock Object of my WCF service interface. Then I setup the call to the service which will be used in the constructor of my view model as shown above. Everything works like a charm now. I hope this is useful for someone since I think the idea the of the ClientChannelWrapper is great for Silverlight <-> WCF communication. Please feel free to comment on this solution!

Comment: Don't be sorry to answer your onw question. You found an answer that works for your problem before anyone else provided a possible solution. Why should you not share that answer with anyone else facing the same/a similar problem?